# App Engine Ruby flex environment app.yaml is ignoring env_variables RAILS_ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

We are using GAE with Ruby flexible environment, and we're trying to deploy a rails app with staging configurations (i.e. RAILS_ENV=staging).

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml we should be able to set the value of RAILS_ENV configuring an app.yaml with:

```
env_variables:
  RAILS_ENV: 'staging'
```

However, when we run:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

A (temporary) Dockerfile is generated with

```
# Temporary. Will be moved to base image later.
ENV RACK_ENV=production \
    RAILS_ENV=production \
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
```

Which results in a deployment in the PRODUCTION environment (default value for RAILS_ENV).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This actually looks like a misfeature, as the overview documentation states that variables like [`RAILS_ENV`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime#environment_variables) and [`NODE_ENV`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables) get set to 'production' on purpose. These should actually be treated as default values which can be overridden in `app.yaml`.

I've created a defect report which you can star for updates here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1399

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something that shouldn't happen, since it contradicts the docs. This should be posted as an issue on [the github issue page for the Flexible Environment Ruby Docker image](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docker).